# Highlight specific cells based on input in a specific range

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to write a Vba code that highlights the larger cells in the color of the smaller cells next to it, when the number is typed in cell C25. ie if I typed 1 in Cell C25, all the large cells with 1 in any of the 4 cells to the right of it will turn orange. and the same for the numbers 1-5. I have asked chat-gpt multiple times, but it never gives me a code that works

[image: Image of my excel sheet]

```
Sub HighlightCellsBasedOnReference()
    Dim targetNumber As Integer
    Dim targetColorIndex As Integer
    Dim originalColors As Variant
    Dim cellToCheck As Range

    ' Get the target number and color index from cell C25
    On Error Resume Next
    targetNumber = Range("C25").Value
    targetColorIndex = Range("C25").Interior.ColorIndex
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Define the range to check (columns F, I, L, O, R, U, X, AA, AD, AG from rows 3 to 22)
    Dim checkRange As Range
    Set checkRange = Range("F3:F22,I3:I22,L3:L22,O3:O22,R3:R22,U3:U22,X3:X22,AA3:AA22,AD3:AD22,AG3:AG22")

    ' Store original colors of the cells to be checked
    originalColors = checkRange.Interior.ColorIndex

    ' Check if the target number is between 1 and 5
    If targetNumber >= 1 And targetNumber <= 5 Then
        ' Determine the start row based on the target number
        Dim startRow As Integer
        startRow = (targetNumber - 1) * 4 + 3

        ' Loop through each cell in the check range
        For Each cellToCheck In checkRange
            ' Check if the cell's value and color index match the target
            If cellToCheck.Value = targetNumber And cellToCheck.Interior.ColorIndex = targetColorIndex Then
                ' Highlight the corresponding cell to the left based on the range
                If cellToCheck.Row = startRow Then
                    cellToCheck.Offset(0, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = targetColorIndex
                End If
            End If
        Next cellToCheck
    Else
        MsgBox "Please enter a number between 1 and 5 in cell C25.", vbExclamation
    End If

    ' Restore original colors
    checkRange.Interior.ColorIndex = originalColors
End Sub.
```

This is the code it gave me, but it just ended up removing all the colors in the smaller cells. (All the larger cells are one cell. so E3, E7, E11, E15 and E19, same for all of them)

Comment: You say you want 4 columns to match the color, but you seem to be working with 10 in your code and showing 8 in the image. If you provided data to work with then some may have a go. I would be looking to use conditional formatting though.

Comment: sorry, might have been to general in my description, there are 5 larger cells in columns E, H,K,N,Q,T,W and Z. each of these cells have 4 smaller cells next to it in the column to the right, in the range 3-22. what i was wondering was if there is a code that will highlight the larger cell, in the same color as the smaller one next to it, if I input a number in Cell C25. So that if I put Strategy 1 in cell C25, all the larger cells with number 1 in any of the 4 smaller cells one to the right of it gets highlighted in the color of strategy 1.

Comment: Then adapt what I showed you in my answer - change the ranges so you work in pairs etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, perhaps like this:

[image]

Only entered 2 cond F rules, but enough to show it works.

Comment: This question is screaming for conditional formatting, I was wondering why somebody was using VBA for this :-)